# Should I use Model/Class to access state object properties safely?

Tags: redux

Coming from the iOS/swift programming world, I find the common way to access specific state properties too generic, and I'd like to have your opinion on the subject

Considering the following Redux state (which might be a bit too nested already) :

```
lights: {
    room1: {
        items: {
            1: {
                rgb: false,
                isOn: false,
                value: 50,
                color: -1,
                title: "Desk light"
            },
            2: {
                rgb: false,
                isOn: false,
                value: 50,
                color: -1,
                title: "Groupe 2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the following selector :

```
export const getLight = (state, roomId, itemId) =>
state.lights[roomId].items[itemId];
```

then in a component, I map the stateToProps with the following:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        light: getLight(state, ownProps.roomId, ownProps.itemId)
    };
}
```

this is where the question (finally) is.

I can access the different properties of the light through `this.props.light.isOn` for example; but the `isOn` part doesn't provide any kind of string checking, and in case I modify the state I would then have to update all the components that rely on the property.

I was thinking of using a Light class that I would use like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        light: Light(getLight(state, ownProps.roomId, ownProps.itemId))
    };
}
```

Is that a good practice in React/Redux or is there something else that is used in such a case?

One last thing, I have also a generic action `updateLight` for which I provide a dictionary for the key I want to update. Once again, I have to pay attention to the keys of the dictionary so that they exactly match the state keys. 
I don't see how the `Light` class would help me...except if I list the keys in another enum or something which then would result in a lot of boilerplate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure the fields in your items is using classes in your redux store:

```js
class Light {}

lights: {
    room1: {
        items: {
            1: Light
        }
    }
}
```

This way when you use the `getLight` selector you get a class instance, rather than plain object. Any change to that class will be reflected in all the items in the list.
If you want deeper control over fields and their possible values, other options such as [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [Flow](https://flow.org/) might be more suited for you.

On a side note, you mentioned that the store might be too nested. Redux recommends [normalizing you store](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) to make it work in a way more similiar to a relational DB.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use Model/Class to access state object properties safely?

In React, your component can use the mapped state directly.
For updating of state, you can dispatch an action which will be handled via reducer.

**UNTESTED CODE:**

```
// Reducer.js

// Changes for the state data shape
const initialState = {
  rooms: {
    /*
    room1: {
      items: [
        {
          id: 0, // ID
          rgb: false,
          isOn: false,
          value: 50,
          color: -1,
          title: "Desk light",
          type: "Light", // additional attribute for Item
        },
      ]
    }
    */
  }
};

export const rooms = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UPDATE_ITEM:
      const items = [...state.rooms[action.roomId].items];
      let updateItem = items.find(item => item.id === action.itemId);
      // do something with updatedItem
      return {
        ...state.rooms,
        [action.roomId]: {
          items: items.map(item => (
            item.id === action.itemId ? updatedItem : item
          )),
        }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// YourComponent.js

function mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const { rooms } = state;
  return {
    rooms,
  };
}

function mapDispatchtoProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateItem: (item) => {
      // dispatches UPDATE_ITEM action
      // handled by reducer
      dispatch(updateItem(item));
    }
  };
}

render() {
  const { rooms, updateItem } = this.props;
  return (
    { Object.values(rooms).map(room => (
        <Room key={room.id}>
          { room.items.map(item => (
            <Item key={item.id}
              onChange={() => this.updateItem(item)}
              {...item} // item props
            />
          ))}
        </Room>
    ))}
  );
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```